# How to read and write to php socket in one program?

Tags: php, html, sockets, php-socket

Here I wish to pass a message from client to server and write a response back to the client through the server program. Actually I have kept my database at the server side and trying to send data back to the client according to the clients input. The sending part from client to server and retrieving data from the server is ok. I want some idea to write back to the client as a response

Here is my server program

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            //socket_close($sock);
            $isread=false;
            $address="127.0.0.1";
            $port="1332";
            $sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Socket creation failed..!");
            socket_bind($sock,$address,$port) or die("Socket binding failed..!");
            socket_listen($sock) or die("Socket listen failed..!");
            $accept=socket_accept($sock) or die("Socket accept failed..!");
            $read=socket_read($accept,1024);
            //echo $read;
            if($read)
                $isread=true;
            $ar=array();
            $ar=explode("@",$read);
            print_r($ar);
            if($isread==true)
                getData('testdata','student',$accept,$ar[0],$ar[1]);

            function getData($dbName,$tblName,$acc,$control,$value)
            {
                mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Connection failed..!");
                mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("Connection failed..!");
                $cmd="SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE '$control'='$value'";
                $query=mysql_query($cmd) or die("Query execution failed..! ".mysql_error());
                $rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
                $cols=mysql_num_fields($query);
                for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++)
                {
                    $tbl=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    for($j=0;$j<$cols;$j++)
                    {
                          socket_write($acc,$tbl[0]+"@");
                    }
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
            socket_close($sock);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my client program

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="myclient.php" method="POST">
            <select name="data">
                <option value="RegNo">RegNo</option>
                <option value="Name">Name</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="mytext"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="Submit" name="btn"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    $iswrite=false;
    if(isset($_POST['btn']))
    {
        $d=$_POST['data'];
        $s=$_POST['mytext'];
        $address="127.0.0.1";
        $port="1332";
        if(isset($d) && isset($s))
        {
            $sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create socket");
            $con=socket_connect($sock,$address,$port) or die("Cannot connect to socket");

            socket_write($sock,$d);
            socket_write($sock,"@");
            $write=socket_write($sock,$s);
            if($write)
                $iswrite=true;

            if($iswrite)
            {
                $read=socket_read($sock,1024);
                echo $read;
            }

            socket_close($sock);
        }
    }
```

Please give me an idea.

Comment: You could send "Hi", or is that too informal? Please explain your problem better, preferably with less code.

Comment: Suppose if client sends "Hi" to server then read it from the server and response to the client with a message such as "Hi client" and client should be able read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I tried it.

This is the server's program.

```
<?php
$address="127.0.0.1";
$port="3222";
$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a socket");
socket_bind($sock,$address,$port) or die("Couldnot bind to socket");
socket_listen($sock) or die("Couldnot listen to socket");
$accept=socket_accept($sock) or die("Couldnot accept");
$read=socket_read($accept,1024) or die("Cannot read from socket");
echo $read;
socket_write($accept,"Hello client");
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

This is the client's program.

```
<?php
$address="127.0.0.1";
$port="3222";
$msg="Hello server";

$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("Cannot create a socket");
socket_connect($sock,$address,$port) or die("Could not connect to the socket");
socket_write($sock,$msg);

$read=socket_read($sock,1024);
echo $read;
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Try this one.This works fine.

Comment: But I need to do this in an interactive way.I need to get user inputs from both sides with the use of html. If someone knows how to do it please let me know.

Comment: This will work fine via PHP CLI but not in a web environment for the very reason that PHP does not run client-side. If you want it interactive, with HTML you have to use Javascript and Websockets.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is **always** server-side. What you're showing as your client-side code is not running client-side, but instead, running on your server (i.e. server side).

To work with web sockets, the client side code needs to be in Javascript. Google for web socket tutorials.

[Here's](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/) a good one to get you started.

Comment: > PHP is always server-side. Not so. Atypical, but any host with a PHP install can always run
php scriptName.php
This may not be within a GUI but that too can be resolved via systems like
tclTk invoking | scriptName.php and processing the outputs

Comment: @jobeard: How is invoking a script via `php scriptName.php` not server side? The contrast to server-side will be client-side (as in on the client's browser), and no browser is capable of executing PHP.

Comment: A PHP script is running on the server side. Check. A PHP script can connect to another server. Check. If the PHP from one server can connect to another server, it will be able to act as a client. Check.

Comment: PHP most definitely can be a client. Yeah, not the browser kind of client, but can send various types of requests (udp, tcp) to other PHP and non-PHP servers/APIs.